# How can I change this variable with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm curious as to why this isn't working, here's the code:

```
function Ajax(sUrl, fCallback) {

    var url = sUrl || '';
    var callback = fCallback || function () {};
    var xmlhttp = (function () {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
                } catch (err) {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }());

    this.setUrl = function (newUrl) {
        url = newUrl;
    };

    this.setCallback = function (func) {
        callback = func;
    };

    this.request = function (method, data) {
        if (xmlhttp === null) { return false; }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
                callback(xmlhttp.status, xmlhttp.responseXML, xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        };

        data = data || '';
        data = encodeURIComponent(data);
        if ((/post/i).test(method)) {
            xmlhttp.open('POST', url);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlhttp.send(data);
        } else {
            var uri = data === '' ? url : url + '?' + data;
            xmlhttp.open('GET', uri);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        return true;
    };

    return this;

}

var ajax = new Ajax(''); // sets the url, not necessary for this demonstration
var changed = false;

function change() {
    changed = true;
}

function foo() {
    ajax.setCallback(change);
    ajax.request();
    alert(changed);
}

foo();
```

There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dTqKG/

I feel like the `change` function would create a closure that would indeed change the `changed` variable. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Just an aside: you don't need to return `this` from a function that you are calling as a constructor: that will happen automatically, and it is usual practice to leave it to happen automatically (just don't return anything else).

Comment: @nnnnnn, I suppose I agree . . . it would seem I've been reading too much Crockford @_@ Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ajax.request();` will return before `change()` is called. That is the async nature of the AJAX calls, and the reason why you need the callback as opposed to just getting return value from `send()` method.
Other than that there might be some other issues in the code. I question why wouldn't you use one of the many AJAX frameworks readily available instead of writing your own.

Comment: Thanks for that, I kept it from being asynchronous and it worked. The reason I'm not using a library is for the learning experience, and I don't really see the need for having a library that gives much more functionality than I need. This way is just more lightweight I suppose. I do and don't understand why your explanation is correct, though . . . thanks again!

Comment: Not really AJAX if you keep it from being asynchronous!

Comment: @Zach I suppose this would be a good learning about **async** calls. Your code looked elaborate enough that I assumed you were trying to reinvent the wheel :)